# Как прокинуть IP-адрес через роутер?

Tags: windows, ip, роутер, static-ip

У меня есть статический IP в сети. Дома стоит роутер. Как мне прокинуть IP к определенному ПК, чтоб можно было зайти на него из вне по IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На роутере - раздел Port forward, а дальше - интуитивно, ибо не знаю, какой роутер.

Answer (score 3):

Одного конкретного ответа на данный вопрос не существует. Так как для каждой операционной системы, которая работает в качестве роутера или роутера "из коробки" (в том числе играет роль производитель и модель) имеют различные варианты настроек. Поэтому советую расширить свой вопрос, дополнив его моделью оборудования, или ОС, или еще чем в таком духе.

В общем случае для роутера "из коробки", находите `Port-Forwading` в админке, в качестве внешнего порта/диапазона портов указываете те, которые хотите открыть, в качестве внутренних портов указываете те, на которых работает ваш сервер, кроме того, указываете IP-адрес, присвоенный компьютеру с сервером.

Для Linux с `iptables` вам необходимы правила (например, для перенаправления порта 8080 на порт 80 протокола tcp):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination w.x.y.z:80
```

И так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего у человека Win7, но вот есть еще вопрос, какой доступ он хочет получить? RDP? FTP ? HTTP ? или просто торренты ?

Если ответить на все сразу, то в настройках роутера привязать MAC адрес дом. компа к IP который выдан ему, дальше следуя ответу e_klimin пробросить порты на IP компа, соответственно каждому сервису.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подойти к вопросу совсем сурово и добавить свой компьютер в DMZ роутера, тогда все пакеты будут идти к нему.

Answer (score 0):

Сперва определитесь как будет использоваться ваш комп чтобы знать на какой порт прокидывать, далее по в роутере по мак адресу сетевой карты компа назначить ему определённый IP адрес, и в директории port forward указать порт и IP адрес (этого компа) куда будут пересылаться пакеты. вот и все!