# Разверка сайта на localhost

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Задеплоил свой проект, открывается localhost:8080 . Как можно запустить просто на localhost?

Comment: указать порт номер 80?

Comment: пишет use. Чтото на нем висит? OC ubuntu

Comment: Вы что? Нет конечно. Кто-то его уже слушает. Возможно какой-нибудь nginx или apache.

Comment: Трудно сказать навскидку.

Comment: 16:09:50 Error running Tomcat 7: Address localhost:80 is already in use
16:09:53 Error running Tomcat 7: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Socket closed" =( печаль

Comment: sudo netstat -tpln

Comment: И ищете, кто слушает 80-ый порт.

Comment: Кстати, при некорректном завершении процесса возможно такое, что порт занят, а процесса нет.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько ясно из комментариев, 80 порт занят. Чтобы узнать, кто его слушает, достаточно выполнить

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

Скорее всего, вы увидите :80 и :8080 порты, в правой колонке -- PID/имя процессов.

P. S.: отключите/удалите/перенастройте демона, который сидит на порте, потом должно заработать.

Comment: команда ничего не выводит.. может быть потомучто я на роутере сижу?

Comment: Убедитесь. что и netstat, и grep, и sudo установлены.

Comment: `netstat` пишется один раз. И разве за полвека в бубунте не появилась графическая программка мониторинга сети? Сейчас ведь почти ни кто не умеет выполнять пасы руками в командной строке.

Answer (score -1):

Решил задачу так: пробросил через роутер 80 порт на 8080 с привязкой на локальный ip.

- [Как прокинуть IP-адрес через роутер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/340485/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/340486#340486)
- http://pk-help.com/network/port-router-asus-d-link-tp-link-zyxel/